# Collaborative JSON Viewer/Parser

Tags: javascript, json, collaboration

I'm a fan of online json viewer [jsonviewer.stack.hu](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

Is there any site that allows sharing of parsed json just like [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/) or [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github [Gist](https://gist.github.com) is the best one i've found so far.

Answer (score 1):

Best tool available at [JSON Viewer](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer) where you can test your json data as well as save and share to the world.